# Speciation in NEAT - Advantages of keeping stable number of species

Tags: neat

I found several methods for setting the compatibility distance in NEAT: some normalize it, some don't, some automatically adjust it.

In a few tests I am running, using normalized static compatibility distance, the number of species increase very rapidly, thus suggesting to adjust (e.g. increase) the compatibility distance.

I haven't found however, how to determine a reasonable number of species for my population, which are the benefits of having lots/few species and which are the benefits of having stable vs mutable number of species?